# Compare partial object in an ArrayList Java

Tags: java, list, object, arraylist, object-oriented-database

I have an Object as follows:

```
public class Record{
    Int ID;
    String title;
    Date date;
    Duration time;

    public Record createRecord(int ID, String title, Date date, Duration time){
        this.ID= ID;
        this.title = title;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        return this;
    }
}
```

I am storing multiple objects in a List. While inserting a new record, I need to check if the list already has an object with ONLY the same title and date, and replace the time in it.

I am looking for any solution which can achieve O(1) time.

Comment: which data structure are you using for storing your objects? I would go for HashSet which have searching time complexity of O(1)

Comment: I am using a HashMap with date as the Key and a list of the Object as value. Once I retrieve a list of objects from the HashMap, I need to perform the above operation.

Comment: why not compare by your ID field instead? There isn't much point to having an ID if it can be present in other objects... inversely there's a varying degree of probability to have two objects with the same title and date. Also, there isn't much need to `return this;` in your constructor, in Java the constructor already returns the new object instance.

Comment: @AnthonyAudette Unfortunately the ID is not necessarily unique, hence the problem

Comment: @AakshaySubramaniam how difficult would it be to redesign your program structure to ensure ID's are unique? If an ID isn't unique there isn't much point to having one in the first place.

Comment: On an unrelated one, you might want to turn createRecord into a static factory method

Comment: @AnthonyAudette I am trying to simulate a Database with the combination of Title and Date to be unique.

Comment: if it's a guarantee that the combination of date & time will be unique for each object, you could always create a `String getUniqueID()` method that returns a concatenation of your title & date data

Comment: No matter what you do, your search time with comparing both a String and a Date this will always be greater than comparing a single `int` or a `long`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching in ArrayList for existing element will take you O(n) in case of sorted ArrayList (e.g. you maintain records sorted) it will require O(logn) time. Therefore to achieve desired functionality I'd use Map structure, indexing by title and then by date. Something like this:

```
// Create general records DB
Map<String, Map<Date, Record>> records = new HashMap<>();

// Create sub DB for records with same ID
Map<Date, Record> subRecords = new HashMap<>();

// Assuming you've got from somewhere id, title and rest of the parameters
subRecords.put(recordDate, new Record(id, title, time, duration));
records.put(recordId, subRecords)

// Now checking and updating records as simple as
sub = records.get(someTitle); // Assuming you've got someTitle
if (sub != null) {
   record = sub.get(someDate); // Same for someDate
   if (record != null) {
       record.updateTime(newTime);
   }
}
```

Using Map of Map will prevent from you the need to override equals and hashCode methods, while I'd agree that `Map<String, Map<Date, Record>>` might look a bit fancy or weird. While will provide you with ability to update the records or check for existence within O(1) time. Additional nit is that you do not need to create a record to check for existence or for update, you can directly use Title and Date to retrieve what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by a `HashSet`

and implement the

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(this == obj) return true;
        if(!(obj instanceof Record)) return false;
        Record otherRecord = (Record)obj;
        return (this.time.equals(otherRecord.time) && this.title.equals(otherRecord.title));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {        
        int result = titile != null ? titile.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (time != null ? time.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;

    }
```

And use a hashset to insert

```
   HashSet hset = new HashSet<Record>();
   if(!hset.add(record)){
        hset.remove(record);
        hset.add(record);
   }
```

Then you could convert the HashSet to the List you want.

Comment: Don't compare `String`s with `==`!

Comment: My understand that you need to maintain this list and be able to update records over the time. Hence switching between HashSet and List not a real option considering O(1) requirement. Is should be always a HashSet or some Map.

Comment: The same goes for time.

Comment: to continue same line of @Oleg and previous comment about strings comparison - the hashCode is also far from being optimal, I'd add an explanation on why you need to implement those functions at the first place.

Comment: @ArtemBarger I am modifying it, I never have written a hashcode myself, just generated from the IDE

Comment: @ArtemBarger : If I understand you correctly, are you talking about having type which includes `Hashset` supporting `Record` type. like HashSetRecord type.

Comment: @AkashKC no, not really, I was just saying that switching from set to list will not sustain requirements of O(1) as this list has to be maintained over the time.

Comment: additional problem with HashSet you cannot get a record for update in O(1) time. you do able to verify existence though.

Comment: @ArtemBarger can you give more details about "cannot get a record for update in O(1) time"?

Comment: @armnotstrong how would you retrieve a record from HashSet to update time and duration? Set interface simply doesn't provide any means of get functionality, you can use iterators though which will make you do pass of O(n) to get a record for update.

Comment: @ArtemBarger according to the op, he/she want to check duplicate with time and duration which means we shouldn't *update* the records time and duration fields, if that happens, we should delete the previous one and add a new one, which is O(1).

Comment: I'm citing "I need to check if the list already has an object with ONLY the same title and date, and replace the time in it."... Replace time in it, the way I read it, if record exists you have to update it with new time.

Comment: of course you can find and delete it, while when you also need to copy duration field to keep it same.

Comment: now, when I've read the citing, I've realized that my solution is also not very correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of a Map implementation that gives you `O(1)` access, like `HashMap` or `ConcurrentHashMap` .

Psuedo-code:

```
class Record {
    static class Key {
        Date date
        String title
        // proper hashCode and equals
    }
    Date date
    String title
    int id
    Time time
    Key getKey() {...}
}


Map<Record.Key, Record> recordMap = new HashMap<>();
for (record : records) {
    recordMap.merge(record.getKey(), record, 
                   (oldRecord, newRecord) -> oldRecord.setTime(newRecord.getTime()));
}
```